# Obtain response from MvcResult object

Tags: java, spring, junit, response

I'm using `MvcResult` class in **JUnit Test**.

How can I obtain the object which is returned?

```
MvcResult r = this.mockMvc
            .perform(get("/aaaa?page=1&size=1&status=aaa")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

MockHttpServletResponse response = r.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast it to `Object` with `Gson`

```
 gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                .create();
```

And:

```
Obj ob = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Obj>().getType());
```